# Add non-standard segments with nhapi

Tags: mirth, nhapi

My system has to generate an xml in which the node `ORM_O01.ORDER_DETAIL` must contain the node `ORM_O01.OBRRQDRQ1RXOODSODT_SUPPGRP`, because it has to communicate with Mirth.
I am using the `nhapi` library version `2.5`, in which this node does not contain it.

```
var obr = _ormO01Message.GetORDER().ORDER_DETAIL.OBR;                                
obr.SetIDOBR.Value = "1";
obr.PlacerOrderNumber.EntityIdentifier.Value = "123456";
obr.PlacerOrderNumber.NamespaceID.Value = "6543";
obr.PlacerOrderNumber.UniversalID.Value = "10009";
obr.UniversalServiceIdentifier.Identifier.Value = "NS";
```

Is it possible to add a node in `ORM_O01.ORDER_DETAIL` that is not standard?

Thanks.

```
<ORM_O01.ORDER_DETAIL>
    <ORM_O01.OBRRQDRQ1RXOODSODT_SUPPGRP>
        <OBR>
            <OBR.1>1</OBR.1>
            <OBR.2>
                <EI.1>123456</EI.1>
                <EI.2>6543</EI.2>
                <EI.3>10009</EI.3>
            </OBR.2>
            <OBR.4>
                <CE.1>NS</CE.1>
            </OBR.4>
        </OBR>
    </ORM_O01.OBRRQDRQ1RXOODSODT_SUPPGRP>
</ORM_O01.ORDER_DETAIL>
```

Answer (score 1):

ORM_O01.OBRRQDRQ1RXOODSODT_SUPPGRP [looks like](https://github.com/niquola/health_seven/blob/master/vendor/2.5/ORM_O01.xsd) it actually *is* standard for 2.5, but neither nhapi or hapi (which mirth uses) include it. I wouldn't worry about trying to add it in because mirth probably wouldn't be able to parse it if you did.

See [similar issue](https://www.mirthcorp.com/community/forums/showthread.php?t=217293) where a mirth user needed to strip that group out.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Do you know why, neither hapi nor nhapi, implement it? Thanks.

Comment: My guess would be that the nhapi code was generated from hapi rather than the spec. I don't know why it's like that in hapi. I'm not really an hl7 expert.